# R: How to change colors and shapes in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to make a network using an example data like below but way much bigger

```
data <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "AB", "AD", "AN", "B", "D", 
"GDH"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("AC", "AD", "AG", "B", 
"C", "D", "THG"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))


library(igraph)
g = graph.data.frame(data)
plot(g)
```

which gives me this

[image]

what i want is to 
1- change the color and shape for each cluster (like THG and GDH becomes blue) but prefer randomly because when the data is huge one by one applying it will not be suitable

2- remove the name inside instead put a number close to based on their order in the data for example

```
A   B
A   C
A   D
A   C
B   D
B   C
D   C
```

is 1

```
AB  AC
```

is 2

etc etc

Comment: Have you checked the documentation before asking? See `?igraph::igraph.plotting` for how to manipulate `V(g)$color` and other parameters.

Comment: @Fr. read my question very carefully before you down vote it. if I want to do it manually I can by  `V(g)$color` I said it is difficult to do so, when the data is huge

Comment: I have just read your question again, and I am still unable to see what is stopping you from using the igraph plotting parameters to color the nodes. Perhaps you could (1) give the dimensions of your data ("huge" can mean many things) and (2) show your attempts at using the `igraph` plotting parameters (which are not there so far)?

Comment: P.S. You might also want to clarify what you mean by "one by one applying it will not be suitable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 90% solution.  It does everything that you want except for the component label.

I think that what you are trying to do is get at the connected components of your graph.  That is available through the `biconnected_components` function in {igraph}. I use that to build a vector which indicates which component each vertex is in. You can modify the vertices with the vertex.xxx group of parameters. Below, I change the color,shape and label using the component number.

(Updated to include shape)

```
Components = biconnected_components(g)$components
VComponent = rep(0, length(V(g)))
for(i in 1:length(Components)) { VComponent[Components[[i]]] = i }
plot(g, vertex.color=VComponent, vertex.label=VComponent,
vertex.shape = shapes()[c(1:3,8)][VComponent])
```

[image: Graph]

The default shapes do not allow a lot of variation, although it is possible to add other shapes. [This page](http://igraph.org/r/doc/shapes.html) shows how to add a triangle and a star as options. I am labeling the vertices with the cluster number. You can make the vertices have no label by specifying   `vertex.label = NA`.  But you wanted to place a text label near each component. I do not see how to get the locations of the components to place the text, so I labeled the nodes instead.

Comment: can you also change the shape of each cluster ?

Comment: Yes,  I will add that to the answer.